# Making tables in python from sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a data base at sqlite which contains posts harvested from Facebook. This table has three columns: col1(post_id_main_message), col2(main_message); col3(users_responses_to_main_message).

At third column there are several responses to the main message of col2 separated each other by ***.

I am trying

1. Import sqlite to python.
   Then, I want to create (using python) at csv format a table at which:
2. Separate each response of col3 at a new row.
3. For each separated response of col3 I want to insert a column to identify at what main_message is it responding to.
4. I want to insert a column to retain the id of the main message.

Comment: Typically when asking a Python question, you would show some Python code that you have. Also, what exactly is the question?

Comment: In addition to the code, please share some sample input and output data.